# Unable to apply CSS in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a website that uses OpenTable's reservation widget. In every browser except IE9 (including older versions of IE) I can style and manipulate the widget elements, both through a stylesheet and by using jQuery. But in IE9, the widget shows up with strange styling, and I can't effect it in any way. Even trying a simple test like `$('#OT_form').hide();` has no effect whatsoever.

Here's a temporary link to the site:

http://www.tcmulder.com/jing/reservations

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: It seems that your `form` tag is not closed properly. That gives a different markup  in IE

Comment: Interesting: good eye. If I do the following:
`alert($('#OT_form').children().length > 0 );`
I get `false` for IE9 and `true` for the others. I used jQuery's .replaceWith and .wrap to remove the incorrectly closed form and re-wrap it correctly only if children are false (just IE9 for now).